# How to avoid a variable containing a list of directories being treated as string

Tags: shell-script, directory, string, command-substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

Dir='/home/TEST'
Project="${Dir}/Project.txt"
```

The text file `Project.txt` contains the file type & its path:

```
SOURCE|FILE|TARGET_PATH
TEST|BDL|/LOAN/NDL/XML
TEST|BDL|/LOAN/DL/XML
TEST|BDL|/LOC/DL/XML
TEST|ADU|/LOAN/NDL/XML
TEST|ADU|/LOAN/DL/XML
TEST|ADU|/LOC/DL/XML
```

By revising my own question & the answer provided, I manipulated my code to:

```
while IFS='|' read -r source file path
do
    unset IFS

    if [ "${source}!" != "TEST!" ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    for dir in "${path}"; do
        find "${Dir}${dir}" -type f | grep ^'file' >"${Dir}${dir}"/"${file}"_Totallist.txt
    echo "${Dir}${dir}"
    done

done < "$Project"
```

The result of the echo:

```
/home/ds4078/TEST_XXX/LOAN/NDL/XML

/home/ds4078/TEST_XXX/LOAN/DL/XML

/home/ds4078/TEST_XXX/LOC/DL/XML

/home/ds4078/TEST_XXX/LOAN/NDL/XML

/home/ds4078/TEST_XXX/LOAN/DL/XML

/home/ds4078/TEST_XXX/LOC/DL/XML
```

The `"${file}"_Totallist.txt` were succesfully created in their respective directories which means that the directories are successfully passed.

The problem now is just that the text file is empty, but the original problem was solved. Perhaps there's problem with the `ind "${Dir}${dir}" -type f | grep ^'file' >"${Dir}${dir}"/"${file}"_Totallist.txt`.

Comment: As the question reads now, understanding what you're trying to achieve requires some guesswork. If [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347281/43779) doesn't fully answer you question please consider editing the question to explain up front exaclty what you're trying to achieve, then explain what you're tried so far and the issue you are encountering. As the question stands know it seems to me you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process each directory in `$path` separately you'll need to iterate through the entries in `$path` in an outer loop:

```
    path=`grep "^TEST" ${Dir}/Project.txt | cut -d"|" -f3`

    for dir in $path; do
      for f in `ls -Rd "${Dir}${path}"/* -type f | grep ^${file}`; do
        ${f} >"${Dir}${path}"/"${file}"_total_file_list.txt
      done
    done
```

However, since it seems that the processing loop also refers to the filename in `$file` that matches the directory read from that entry, you'd also need to simultaniously iterate through `$file` in a matching pace. A more straightforward way would be to handle each line in `Project.txt` separately:

```
while read line; do
  IFS='|';
  fields=($line);  # split $line on '|' delimiters
  unset IFS;

  source=${fields[0]}
  file=${fields[1]}
  path=${fields[2]}

  if [ "$source!" != "TEST!" ]
  then
    continue  # skip lines not beginning with "TEST"
  fi

  for f in `ls -Rd "${Dir}${path}"/* -type f | grep ^${file}`
  do
    ${f} >> "${Dir}${path}"/"${file}"_total_file_list.txt
  done

done <Project.txt
```

This uses Bash's [*input field separator*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) to split each record in the input file at the delimiting `|`.

Finally, [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can iterate over files using the builtin pattern matching functionality in bash:

```
for f in "{Dir}${path}"/**/"$file"*; do
  if [ -f "${f}" ]  # check that $f is a file
  then
    ${f} >> "${Dir}${path}"/"${file}"_total_file_list.txt
  fi
done
```

An advantage with using the builtin functionality in Bash to parse the input files and directories is avoiding the need to call external programs, which is likely to result in faster script execution.

For further reading David A. Wheelers essay on [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html) provides useful advice and plenty of examples for handling this sort of processing in a safe and robust manner.

Comment: Thanks @thomasnyman I have one question for the input field separator. If a text contains multiple rows,  for example multiple rows of `TEST|BDL|/LOAN/NDL/XML`, the '|' delimiters will only separate it to `test`, `BDL` & `/LOAN/NDL/XML` but will encounter error after `/LOAN/NDL/XML` & before next line? I read a few examples but all of them used single line text, is there any options that can encounter this problem?

Comment: @Juliet.Y The `while read line; do ...; done < Project.txt` construct is intended to allow the input to be processed one line at a time. In the example in the answer the input field separator is only applied to distinct lines read from `Projects.txt`, not the entire input at once, which was based on a assumption on my part that each line in `Projects.txt` describe a distinct record (and the file and directory names don't contain newlines).

Comment: I've edited the answer to use [recursive shell globs](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) to match the new information regarding the directory structure added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes. (check the last command output.)

**example**

```
$ ls *.txt
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt  test4.txt  test5.txt

$ files=$(ls *.txt)

$ echo ${files}
test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt test4.txt test5.txt

$ echo "${files}"
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
test4.txt
test5.txt
```

so, in your case, you need to use it like this

```
echo "${path}" | while read dir_path
do
       ls -r "${Dir}${dir_path}"
done
```

Also, your find command with grep is not correct. try with xargs

```
find path -type f | xargs grep "pattern"
```